# Circuitikz different ground symbol

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

Is it possible to make circuitikz draw a different ground symbol?
I would like to have a ground symbol with only one horizontal line.
Thanks.

Comment: Of course it is. There is more than one solution, but if you could post an image of the symbol that you need (or a link), it would be easier for us (it sounds quite unusual to me).

Comment: Ground symbols: (http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/11/Signal_Ground.svg), (http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2d/Chassis_Ground.svg), I am looking for something like the following (http://server.ibfriedrich.com/wiki/ibfwikide/images/d/d1/Massesternpunkt1.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to draw the line by yourself, as suggested Thanos. You can also redefine circuitikz ground code or add a new ground symbol. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{ground}{
\anchor{center}{
    \pgfpointorigin
}
\behindforegroundpath{      
    \pgf@circ@res@step=\ctikzvalof{monopoles/ground/width}\pgf@circ@Rlen

    \pgfscope       
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{-\pgf@circ@res@step}}
        \pgfusepath{draw}

        \pgfsetlinewidth{6\pgflinewidth} % thickness

        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-\pgf@circ@res@step}{-\pgf@circ@res@step}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@step}{-\pgf@circ@res@step}}
        \pgfusepath{draw}                       
    \endpgfscope
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[american voltages]
\draw 
(0,0) node [ground] {}
      to [V] (0,2)
;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

You can change the value in the line with the comment "thickness" even with a natural value (i.e. 3pt).

[image]

Comment: Very nice thought!

Comment: @Luigi I know this is old but I really would like to get a variant of this symbol but with 3 horizontal lines. I asked the question on a new thread here. [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/456195/how-to-create-a-different-ground-symbol?noredirect=1#comment1147455_456195)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manually, by just adding a line at a specific point. The following code produces

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [cylinder, gray,fill=gray!30, rotate=0, draw,
    minimum height=5cm, minimum width=2.5cm] (c){Ανιχνευτής Αερίου};
  \draw[red,-] (-2,0) -- (2.5,0);
  \draw[gray,fill=gray, path fading=south] (2.45,0) ellipse (0.15cm and 0.8cm);
%  \draw [-] (0,-1.25) arc [radius=2cm, start angle=0, end angle=90];
  \draw[gray,dashed] (-2,-1.25) arc (-30:30:2.5cm);
  \node at (-2,-0.03) (O) {$\bullet$};
  \draw[black,-] (-2,0) -- (-3,0);
  \draw (-3,0.2) -- (-3,-0.2);
  \draw (-3,0.2) -- (-3.3,0);
  \draw (-3,-0.2) -- (-3.3,0);
  \draw (1,-1.25) -- (1,-1.7);

  \draw (0.8,-1.7) -- (1.2,-1.7);
  \draw (0.85,-1.75) -- (1.15,-1.75);
  \draw (0.9,-1.8) -- (1.1,-1.8);
 \draw (0.95,-1.85) -- (1.05,-1.85);

    \draw (-2.5,0) -- (-2.5,1.5);
    \node at (-2.5,1.5) (O) {$\bullet$};

%  text
  \draw[red] (0,0.1) node[above right] {\footnotesize Κάθοδος};
  \draw (-1.9,0.8) node[above right] {\footnotesize Άνοδος};
  \draw[gray] (2.8,0) node[above right] {\footnotesize Παράθυρο};
  \draw[gray] (2.8,-0.3) node[above right] {\footnotesize Ανιχνευτή};
  \draw[black] (-4,0) node[above right] {\footnotesize Σήμα};
  \draw[red] (-2.7,1.5) node[above right] {\footnotesize $+V_0$};
%  \draw[red, -] (c.top)   -- (c.bottom)
%    node [at end, below, black]   {height};
%  \draw[red, <->] (c.north) -- (c.south)
%    node [at start, above, black] {width};
\end{tikzpicture}
\label{fig:gasDetector}
\caption{Βασική δομή ανιχνευτή αερίου}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

This should be the simplest, yet most anorthodox way of doing it!
I hope it helps!

Comment: what has this code got to do with circuitikz?

Comment: If you see my code, you will discover that groun wasn't made by `node[ground]` but anorthodoxically by just drawing lines. So he can manualy draw two lines (one vertical and one horizontal) in order to get his one line ground! That's the whole idea!