# How to create a different ground symbol?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, circuits

I have read this thread about [creating a custom ground symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74628/circuitikz-different-ground-symbol). I don't still have the skills to edit the solution proposed on this question.
I am trying to get a ground like the one one the following picture:
[image: ground]

Here is an example:

```
    \documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{circuitikz}
    \makeatletter
    \pgfdeclareshape{ground}{
     \anchor{center}{
      \pgfpointorigin
    }
    \behindforegroundpath{      


     \pgf@circ@res@step=\ctikzvalof{monopoles/ground/width}\pgf@circ@Rlen

\pgfscope       
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{-\pgf@circ@res@step}}
    \pgfusepath{draw}

    \pgfsetlinewidth{6\pgflinewidth} % thickness

    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-\pgf@circ@res@step}{-\pgf@circ@res@step}}

    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@step}{-\pgf@circ@res@step}}
    \pgfusepath{draw}                       
     \endpgfscope
     }
     }
     \makeatother

    \begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[american voltages]
    \draw 
    (0,0) node [ground] {}
  to [V] (0,2)
    ;
    \end{circuitikz}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: please provide a mwe! if you use `circuitikz` the `node[ground]{}` should give desired symbol.

Comment: I just edited the question. The MWE is from a former thread of the forum.

Comment: @Zarko indeed it does. But I want the ground symbol with fewer horizontal lines.

Comment: I have never seen `\pgfusepath{draw}` before. Any chance you mean `\pgfusepath{stroke}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{ground}{
 \anchor{center}{
  \pgfpointorigin
}
\behindforegroundpath{      


 \pgf@circ@res@step=\ctikzvalof{monopoles/ground/width}\pgf@circ@Rlen

\pgfscope       
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{-\pgf@circ@res@step}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}                       

\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-\pgf@circ@res@step}{-\pgf@circ@res@step}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@step}{-\pgf@circ@res@step}}

\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-0.67\pgf@circ@res@step}{-1.5\pgf@circ@res@step}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.67\pgf@circ@res@step}{-1.5\pgf@circ@res@step}}

\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-0.33\pgf@circ@res@step}{-2\pgf@circ@res@step}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.33\pgf@circ@res@step}{-2\pgf@circ@res@step}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}                       
 \endpgfscope
 }
 }
 \makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[american voltages]
\draw 
(0,0) node [ground] {}
to [V] (0,2)
;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I set the thickness back to 1 so I could fix the thickness problem. Please, can we make the ground symbol smaller because it looks too big, almost as big as the voltage source.

Comment: @mandresybilly Better now?

Comment: Absolutely yes!